# Why aren't installshield Java packages found?

Tags: java, unix, build, installshield

In an older software project, sometimes we are experiencing problems building an InstallShield-based installer, written in Java, on Solaris x86 5.10. Most of the time it just works, though. What happens is that the Java compiler (javac) can't find com.installshield.* packages, spitting out error messages like this:

```
package com.installshield.util does not exist
```

I have relatively little experience with Java and don't know the source I'm building either -- what could be the reason for javac sometimes not finding com.installshield.* packages, although it mostly does? Might it depend on an environment variable, or downloading of said packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When javac compiles your code, you have to tell it where to look for the classes your code depends on. This is controlled in two ways:

1. Using the `-classpath` command-line switch for javac
2. Using the CLASSPATH environment variable

Check how those two are being handled in your projects. For more information, consult ["Setting the class path"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) in Java documentation.

Comment: It seems that the relevant variable is the $IS_HOME, really, but you're close enough :) I found that the $IS_HOME directory wasn't mounted, which explained the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath settings. You may want to specify the location of the JAR file containing this package at compile time using the `-classpath` switch.

`javac -classpath path/to/foo.jar *.java`

Comment: Classpath can be controlled through $CLASSPATH as well, right? Also, do you know which jar com.installshield.* correspond to? Maybe several jars?